# Using multiple directives with one main directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Currently, angular-redactor.js from https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor is being used in our application. The goal is to create a new angular directive that can handle any text editor, not just redactor.

Is there a way to call angular-redactor directive used in that approach with another, new parent directive that can display the exact same thing or based on the configuration and different text editor directive.

Functionally in the HTML it looks like this right now:

```
<textarea
     id="title-input"
     ng-model="title"
     ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
     height="26px"
     style="resize:none; max-height: 32px"
     redactor="{  buttonsHide: ['link', 'super-script', 'subscript', 'symbol']}">
</textarea>
```

The goal would be to have it look like this:

```
<my-custom-directive
     id="title-input6"
     ng-model="title"
     ng-disabled="!hasPermission('editPageTitle')"
     editor-config="fullToolbar"
     editor-type="redactor">
</my-custom-directive>
```

Where, the directive should handle things in a way that it converts it back into the first one to be rendered by the browser. If editor-type is changed it should point to that directive and render that text editor.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the function version of the `template` property of the DDO.

> ## template
>
> HTML markup that may:
>
> - Replace the contents of the directive's element (default).
>
> Value may be:
>
> - A function which takes two arguments `tElement` and `tAttrs` (described in the compile function api below) and returns a string value.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)

Comment: could I do an if statement (switch statement) or something to switch between templates within on template function?